# Compile openCV with CMake: set architecture and optimization flags

Tags: optimization, architecture, opencv, cmake

I need to compile OpenCV for i486 architecture. I would like to set optimization flags to O3. The problem is that can't find a way to set compiler flags in cmake file or with configuration script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CMake allows you to set your compiler flags on a configuration basis. By default, if you choose the *Release* configuration, the optimization flags will probably be enabled. If you want to turn them on yourself, use:

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O3")
```

and choose the Release configuration (you could also do this using the Cache or the GUI):

```
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
```

#### Relevant doc:

- [CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#variable%3aCMAKE_LANG_FLAGS_RELEASE)
- [CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#variable%3aCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)

NB: replace C by CXX if you use C++

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can either set the `CFLAGS` or `CXXFLAGS` as environment variables before you run `cmake`. Alternatively, have a look at using the [CMAKE_C_FLAGS](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables) inside the relevant CMakeLists.txt files.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
./opencv/cmake/OpenCVCompilerOptions.cmake
```

Line 29:

```
set(OPENCV_EXTRA_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O3")
```

Note the overrides at the top though.